# Suggesting to elaborate the Custom Close Reason #2 (seeking for work or workers)

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Currently, the Custom Close Reason #2 says,

> Questions asking for freelancers to complete work are off-topic because it is essentially advertising, not asking answerable questions. If you need workers, you can check out [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). For more information, see the [Help Center](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

So, it declares off-topic posts that are essentially an advertisement of **seeking freelancers**.

But there is an opposite side of the problem, if a question is essentially an advertisement of **offering** OP's freelancing services. I've seen several posts of this nature, here's the most recent one:

- [Available for Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/9533/)

---

**Question:** Shouldn't we elaborate the text to accommodate this concern? Like this (diff highlighted bold):

> Questions **offering freelancing services or** asking for freelancers to complete work are off-topic because it is essentially advertising, not asking answerable questions. If you need **work or** workers, you can check out [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). For more information, see the [Help Center](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Hmm… 17 days since the question has been asked, 1 view from an indexing crawler. There must be a serious reason for such a drastic drop of activity…